# Proving the continuity of the two variables function at point?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I want to know if this function is continue on $(0,0)$ or not.
$$
g(x,y)= \begin{cases} 
      \frac{x^3-y^3+(x-y)^2}{x^2+y^2} & (x,y) \neq(0,0), \\
      1 & (x,y)=(0,0) 
   \end{cases}
$$
I am asked to use the partial functions $g(0,y)$, $g(x,0)$ and the $g(x,x)$ then deduce the continuity of function globally but I do not see the link between all these functions.
In single variable calculs, to study the continuity I'm used to use the limits.

Comment: It is **not** continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks, what interests me is the why? and the procedure to be followed in order to be able to deal with other functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are asking you to view the function keeping one of the values constant, at the value for the discontinuity (i.e. $(0,0)$) since you know that the function is continuous on all the other points, that's how these functions relate to your original one. Then, for instance, with the first suggestion, you end up with the definition
$$
g(0,y)=g(y)=
\begin{cases} 
      \frac{-y^3+y^2}{y^2} & y \neq0, \\
      1 & y=0 
\end{cases}$$
which is one-variate and you can apply your limits knowledge to show whether it is continuous at $y=0$. Similarly, you can use the other two (i.e. $g(x,0)$ and $g(x,x)$) to see whether or not they are as well continous at that point. Eventually, you will find out they are not as mentioned in the comments.